# Bash script: Show progress indicator until while loop completes

Tags: bash

I have been able to show progress indicators while certain processes run until they complete but I have not been able to get the code right to show the same progress indicator when I run a while loop. For instance, I do this when I ping inside a script:

```
/bin/ping -c 10 $ipaddress > /pinglog & PID=$!
printf "["
while kill -0 $PID 2> /dev/null; do
    printf "."
    sleep 1
done
printf "] "
```

I can also show progress using the sleep command inside a script:

```
sleep 30 & PID=$!
printf "["
while kill -0 $PID 2> /dev/null; do
 printf  "."
 sleep 1
done
printf "] "
```

Both of these examples work and my output looks like this:

```
[.........................}
```

The dots continue every second until the command completes, which is what I want. But I am now trying to get this same output using a while loop, and I am unable to get the results I am after. Here is what I have so far.

```
while [[ ! $(/bin/grep -wo -m1 $VAR1 /logfile) ]] & PID=$!
printf "["
while kill -0 $PID 2> /dev/null; do
    printf "."
    sleep 1
done
printf "] "
do
sleep 5
done
echo $VAR1 was found
```

This runs however it does not stop when the string is found and the output looks like this:

```
[.] [.] [.] [.] [.] and on and on...
```

I have tried moving the actual while loop do, sleep 5 and done above the first printf statement but the results are worse and I do not even get the progress indicator output. How can I fix this so that I get the same progress indicator output as my first 2 examples give me and it stops when my pattern is found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the issue. To have the [........] output format you have to start the first printf "[" before the first while loop even begins. Then put the sleep 5 command in the background and use the second while loop on its PID, instead of the initial while loop itself, because we want to kill the sleep 5 command and not the while loop itself. This will allow the dots to repeat inside of the brackets every second instead of every 5 seconds and allow the search-string to be found.  Finally put the last printf "]" outside of the last done to complete the formatting after the while loop for the search-string ends. This prevents a repeating [.] every five seconds. This is what worked for me:

```
printf "["
while [[ ! $(/bin/grep -wo -m1 $VAR1 /logfile) ]]
do
sleep 5 & PID=$!
while kill -0 $PID 2> /dev/null; do
    printf "."
    sleep 1
done
done
printf "] "
echo $VAR1 was found
```

Answer (score 1):

The command tested by `while` is the last command prior to the `do`. So your loop is basically `while ...; printf "] "; do ... ; end`, and since the `printf` will never fail, the `while` will never terminate.

It is not clear to me what you expect to test with the `while` loop, though. If the expectation is that the compound command `[[ ! $(/bin/grep -wo -m1 $VAR1 /logfile) ]] &` will be tested, you should be aware that when you run a command in the background, the status code only reflects whether `bash` was able to fork a child in order to run the backgrounded command (which is almost always the case). The status code of a command is not available until the command completes, so it is more or less pointless running it in the background if you only want to check the status code.

You can background an entire `while` loop, if that is what you are hoping to do; put the `&` after the `done` which terminates the `while` compound statement. That's probably what you are actually looking for:

```
printf "["
while ! grep -wqm1 "$VAR1" logfile; do
  sleep 1
done &
while kill -0 $! 2>/dev/null; do
  printf "."
done
printf "] "
```

Note: The `-q` option to `grep` causes it to just produce a status return. (With that change, `-m1` is actually redundant.) That avoids having to use `[[` to test the output. Unless you are 100% certain that `$VAR1` cannot contain whitespace or shell metacharacters, you should surround the expansion with quotes. There is no need to store `$!` in a variable, since it will continue to contain the same value until you background some other command.

Comment: I'm testing whether or not a pattern exist in a certain log file using a while loop. While I wait on the pattern to appear I want to show a progress indicator, like I presented in my first 2 examples, using another while loop. So a nested loop so to speak. The printf [......] should stop when the pattern appears.

Comment: Just reading back over what you said. However the printf will/should fail/complete/whatever...when the PID for the initial while loop terminates (when the pattern is found). But it doesn't. At least not with this code.

Comment: @user53029: `printf` won't fail. Why should it?

Comment: It will now. I have re-coded it. See the answer I posted.Your answer got me thinking and running more test, so thank you for that.

Comment: @user53029: You are now running `sleep 5` in the background, which is, IMHO, rather pointless. You could just as well write `for ((i = 0;i < 5;++i)); do printf "."; sleep 1; done` and leave out the whole `while kill -0` loop. What you really want to do is something like `printf "["; while ! grep -wq "$VAR1" logfile; do sleep 1; done & while kill -0 $! 2>/dev/null; do printf "."; done; printf "] "`